# user was removed

Tags: support, reputation, user-accounts, profile-page

When does that happen?

I found [a 4+ in my sum](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/1492/anna-v?tab=reputation)  and tried to see for what, and got "user was removed" instead of a link to the question.

Answer (score 5):

That's explained in [What does "user was removed" mean and why did my reputation change because of it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126470/what-does-user-was-removed-mean-and-why-did-my-reputation-change-because-of-it). Basically, when another user's account is deleted, any votes they may have cast for you are reverted and your reputation can change accordingly.