# Reputation decreases without reason

Tags: discussion, support, reputation

For the past few days I have noticed that for no reason that my reputation is decreasing. I mean to say that when I am logging out one day, I see a certain reputation and when I log in the next day, I see my reputation has decreased by about 20 points or so and in my reputation change bar, there is no such change visible. I further checked but found no downvoting of question nor answer or any other things(migration). I don't have exact records but I can show you one proof.

According to what I came to know, one gets to review first posts and late answers after getting a reputation of 500 at least. Now if you read my [Review](https://physics.stackexchange.com/review/first-posts/history?userId=89965) history you will see that I started reviewing on 20th Sept. 2015. But my [Reputation change](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/89965/aniket?tab=reputation) history will show you that I attained 500 rep only on 21st Sept. And I am quite confident that it is no minor computer or server error. This thing is happening to me for the last two to three days.

Can anybody tell me what is wrong? Is there any other way of losing rep that I don't know or have not considered? It may be that some user might have deleted his/her account. But I was not informed about it or my rep loss concerning his account removal.Please help.

Comment: I asked a related question on the mother meta. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/253831/262980

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You are editing a lot of posts which are closed and have a negative score. Such questions are regularly deleted by an [automatic deletion routine](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92006/263383) (often termed the "roomba").

When a question is deleted, all associated reputation gains and losses are reversed. In particular, the 2 reputation you gained from suggesting an edit that was subsequently approved are lost. I don't believe that there is an indication in the reputation history that this happens - the +2 from a week ago or so simply vanish from it.

If you don't want this to happen, don't make edits to posts that do not fix the reasons for closure/deletion.

Another reason for losing reputation is [users that are removed](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1289/50583) and have upvoted you, but this is usually indicated by a `user was removed` in your [reputation tab](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/89965/aniket?tab=reputation).

Comment: Hitting the `show removed posts` checkbox in the Reputation tab will show you -2s from edits to posts that got deleted.